# Error adding another Google account

Tags: google-account, accounts, htc-hero

Device: T-Mobile G2 (UK) / HTC Hero OS: 2.1

I have a primary gmail account, a second Gmail account, and a Google Apps account. I'd now like to add another Google Apps account.

However, whenever I try, I get a "you don't have a network connection / This could be a temporary problem or your phone may not be provisioned for data services. lease try again when connected to a mobile network, or connect to a Wi-Fi network. If the problem continues, call Customer Care" message. However I've tried this from 3 cities, across a few weeks, from where I'm always able to access internet and Google accounts.

I presume there's no limit of 3, so what else can I try?

Edit - 3rd Jan - I just tried removing an existing (working) gmail account. I can't add the new account, or put back the removed account - new error is "Can't establish a reliable data connection to the server./This could be a temporary problem or your phone may not be provisioned for data services. If it continues, call Customer Care.". This is on WiFi and 3G - whilst the process was trying I received (pull) email! There's something really wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again earlier today, and found it working. Cause of the fix might be: a) enabling multiple login on this account; b) migrating the Google Apps domain to the latest version; c) time, and it fixing itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have 4 Google accounts, so no there's not a limit of 3.  I'm guessing trying two Apps accounts is the problem.  Try adding another standard (gmail) Google account and see if that works.

**Edit:** I'd try a factory reset at this point.

Comment: I don't have another gmail account - can anyone verify?

Comment: That's not it.  Just added two apps accounts to my one Gmail account.  Sorry I don't have an answer but at least we eliminated a couple of possibilities.  Have you verified that your internet connection is active at that moment?  Had a problem yesterday where Juice Defender kept knocking mine out while trying to send GV messages.

Comment: Agree, I have 3 Google Apps accounts, and one normal Gmail account on my phone, with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did a Network reset on my phone, and it fixed this issue!

Comment: Can you tell us how you did that? It is worth mentioning that all the network related details, such as saved Wi-Fi passwords and APNs would be removed by doing network settings reset.